# use python to work with cli

Tags: python, linux, command-line-interface

I am writing a script to search through a database using the databases cli. I have been able to access the database with python using os.system(commands to access database). However the .system function will not enter any commands into the cli.

Comment: Why use these (unknown) CLI commands and not python libraries to this (unknown) database?

Comment: Why don't you try to use pymysql?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve] of the code that isn't working, and please mention the database that is being used so that we can provide useful answers.

Comment: There should be a better way to do this, but you can run commands interactively using the subprocess module.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the database you're using might be expecting input via the keyboard (i.e. it's waiting for input). If that's the case, then you're not going to be able to use `system` for that -- you'll need to start the database CLI process and then manage communication with it.

Here's a simple example. Let's start with a simple app that takes in data via standard input and writes it back out. This would be like your database CLI program.

```
# cli.py
s = input()     # Avoid input() on Python 2!
print("Hello, %s!" % s)
```

And here is the driver (the code you're writing)

```
# driver.py
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(['python3', './cli.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
try:
    outs, errs = proc.communicate(b'world', timeout=2)
    print(outs.decode('utf-8'))
except:
    print('An error occurred.')
```

Expected output:

```
Hello, world!
```

So you'll need to orchestrate all of this to drive commands into the database CLI and read the results out. This sounds like an awful time -- as cricket_007 stated, the database probably has a way to access it without going through the CLI.

If you absolutely need to continue down this route, take a look at the [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect) module, which should handle much of the complexity of this for you.